# Write to Text File Using List

Tags: c#-4.0, file-io

I have list with 100 properties.So If I have thousands of records,my application will hang up while writing to text file.

So Is there easy and faster way of writing to text file.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you writing your file? please attach your code so we can see how to help you.

Comment: using (_streamWriter = new StreamWriter(FilePath(Constants.Data, filename)))
                {
                    if (_myList!= null && _myList.Count > 0)
                    {
                       _streamWriter.Write(_textFileHeader.DataColumnHeader(columnnames));foreach (String sublist in _mylist)
                        {  _streamWriter.Write(sublist.Name);}

Comment: I have used FileStream and StreamWriter to write the file,since I have 100 properties,I need to write 100 lines of code to write each proerty to text file.Is there easy way to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make all this work load asynchronously, this way you don't overuse/overload the main thread and keep your app/UI responsive. You can manage it this way:

```
protected void buttonSaveClick(sender object, EventArgs e) //Assuming you call your save from a button
{
    string filePath = FilePath(Constants.Data, filename));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(var sublist in _mylist) 
    {
        //This will loop only through object's public properties
        foreach(var prop in sublist.GetType().GetProperties())
            if(prop.CanRead)
                sb.AppendLine(prop.GetValue(sublist, null));
    }

    buttonSaveClick.Enabled = false; //Disable the UI so the user can't cause an error clicking again

    try
    {
        await WriteTextAsync(filePath, _textFileHeader.DataColumnHeader(columnnames));
        await WriteTextAsync(filePath, sb.ToString());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        buttonSave.Enabled = true; //Enable UI again on error
        //Log and/or show error to user
    }

    buttonSave.Enabled = true; //Enable UI again on success
}

private async Task WriteTextAsync(string filePath, string text)
{
    byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

    using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
        FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
        bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
    {
        await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help,but if I have 100 of proeprties,I will need to write 100 lines code,is there a better way of accesing the property valuse at once?

Comment: How are your properties/object with properties defined?

Comment: Am using entity framework,and defining all the properties and getting them to list and then looping

Comment: Do you write only values or do you need to write name/value of property?

Comment: I need to write only vlaues

Comment: Check the edit, new foreach statement will loop through public properties of your object